# Using postgres partitions to improve read/writes

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, partitioning

I have a table called `users`. As it grows to have a few hundred million rows, some read/write queries are slowing down.
I can see some lock contention as I insert new users, and querying  the number of users for a given customer can be extremely slow.
I am wondering if there is a way to optimize it by using partitions?

The users table contains all the users for different customers.  Some customers have a few thousand users, while others have 100 million users.

When a brand new user connects to the system a record for them gets inserted into the users table.

If a user returns and logs in, then the record can be upserted with details about their login location, user-agent etc.

The table has the following columns

| ID (uuid) | customer (uuid) | username (varchar) | name (varchar) | properties (jsonb) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32432-432432-43243 | 324324-432432-4324324 | bob@intel.com | Bobby | { location : apac, device : x86 } |

I was thinking about partitioning by customer, as usually all queries look for users or insert users for a given customer. But the problem is some customers have hundreds of millions of users, while others only have a few thousand, so I thought the partitions could get pretty uneven.

Is there an alternative of good pattern to follow to optimize this single table.

I have looked a at list partitioning by customer but I think I'll end up with some tiny partitions and some will be huge. The customer IDs are also not finite as new customers can sign up all the time.

Hash partitioning might be reasonable, but wasn't sure the implications this might have, if I'm trying to count all users belonging to a single customer and this has to hit multiple partitions.

Comment: Before you consider partitioning this kind of table, consider optimizing your most time-consuming SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE statements by adding indexes appropriate to your statements. See Markus Winand's [https://use-the-index-luke.com/](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) e-book. You have correctly identified some of the hassles associated with desiging and using partitions. It's a vale of tears.

Comment: All the complaints seem (based on the very limited info we have) to be better addressed by indexing or tuning than by partitioning.